# Error al recargar fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Buenas tardes estoy presentando el siguiente problema, al intentar recargar un fragment la aplicación queda colgada y luego el celular se reinicia.

El fragment AdminComment muestra un listView que cuando se presiona uno de estos objetos del listView abre un dialog (DialogAdminRecomendation) y este da dos opciones Aceptar cambios y cancelar. Al final del metodo createSimpleDialog estoy agregando la siguiente linea de codigo para que se recargue el Fragment AdminComment que es el contenedor del ListView:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Favor agradeceria mucho si me ayudan indicandome si estoy cometiendo un error o si me dan una idea de como solucionarlo.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Adjunto metodo CreateSimpleDialog

```
public AlertDialog createSimpleDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Aceptar Cambios")
            .setMessage("Esta seguro de aceptar los cambios")
            .setPositiveButton("SI",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            listener.onPossitiveButtonClickInsert(idMachinePointAux,titleAux,bodyCommentAux,usuarioFinalAux);
                            //envio correo avisando
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Eliminar Recomendación",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            listener.onNegativeButtonClickDelete(idMachinePointAux,titleAux,bodyCommentAux,usuarioFinalAux);
                            //envio correo avisando
                        }
                    });
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    return builder.create();
}
```

Saludos Cordiales

Answer (score 0):

Estas realizando dos operaciones contrarias al tratar de realiza la transaccion lo cual es incorrecto

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

> - **attach()** asocia el Fragment con la Actividad.
> - **detach(**) desasocia el
>     Fragment con la Actividad.

Además `this` debe ser un Fragmento.

---

Puedes agregar un Fragment de esta forma (te sugiero usar `getSupportFragmentManager` en lugar de `getFragmentManager`)

```
 Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NombreFragment");
```

o también mediante el id del Fragment:

```
  Fragment fragment =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment);
```

y se procede a realizar la transacción:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

Te sugiero revises la [**documentacion**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html?hl=es-419) para que entiendas como lograrlo

Comment: cuando te refieres al nombre a "NombreFragment" te refieres al valor android:id del xml del fragment?

Comment: @EstebanSasso puedes usar el Id también mediante findFragmentById(), lo agregué en la respuesta. Te sugiero realices un pequeño ejemplo para que entiendas mejor los Fragments, mira este tutorial es recomendable: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/09/android-aplicaciones-fragmento/

Comment: si te comprendo de eso, yo estoy utilizando el findFragmentById pero este me esta retornando null, como que no encontrara el Fragment, mi caso es que llamo a android:id="@+id/admincommentView" a través de getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.admincommentView); y de igual forma retorna null

Comment: Ok si usas   getActivity().getSupportFragmentMamager...... El fragment con id admincommentView debe estar dentron del layout que se carga en la Activity mediante setContentView(.....);

Comment: El codigo de mi fragment es el siguiente:     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/admincommentView"
    android:tag="adminCommentExample"
    tools:context="tesis.android.expocode.com.loginsqllite.AdminComment">

Comment: <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewAdminComment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
 esta correcto llamar al id R.id.admincommentView?

Comment: Este layout se debe cargar en la actividad.

Answer (score -1):

Una forma de recargar un fragment sería así:

```
FragmentAdminComment frag = new FragmentAdminComment();  
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```